# Python3 on Ubuntu giving errors on help() command

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, python-3.4

I used help() in the python3 shell on Ubuntu 14.04
I got this output
Please help , don't know whats wrong.

```
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> help()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/_sitebuiltins.py", line 98, in __call__
import pydoc
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/pydoc.py", line 65, in <module>
import platform
File "/home/omega/platform.py", line 2, in <module>
print("System    : ",platform.uname().system)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'uname'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [`platform`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html) is the name of a stdlib module, which `help` uses. By creating a module of your own with the same name that occurs before the stdlib in your `sys.path`, you're preventing Python from using the standard one.

The fact that your own `platform` module tries to use the stdlib module of the same name just compounds the problem. That isn't going to work; your `import platform` inside that module is just importing itself.

The solution is to not collide names like this. Look at the [list of the standard modules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/), and don't create anything with the same name as any of them if you want to use features from that module, directly or indirectly.

In other words: Rename your `platform.py` to something else, or put it inside a package.

Comment: @MeghdeepRay: The answer already says how you fix it: "Rename your `platform.py` to something else, or put it inside a package." And, more generally, don't give any of your own top-level modules or scripts the same name as any of the stdlib modules.

Answer (score 0):

```
File "/home/omega/platform.py", line 2, in <module>
print("System    : ",platform.uname().system)
```

This is the problem, go to platform.py and fix it, it will be ok. It says, *platform* has not any method called *uname* you probably misstyped.

Comment: No, he's not trying to call `platform.uname`, he's just calling `help()`. The problem is that _Python_ is trying to call `platform.uname`. And it doesn't just want any old function there, it wants the one documented as part of the stdlib.

Comment: I thought it maybe a bug?

Comment: No, it's not a bug, he's just hiding a stdlib module. (Well, there's _also_ clearly a bug in his code—he has a module named `platform` that imports and tries to use the stdlib module `platform`. But even without that bug, just hiding the stdlib module will break things.)